# ACR to AKS deployment ERROR: The container operating system does not match the host operating system

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I have deployed a windows container which runs successfully in my local system using docker. Moved the image to Azure container registry and deployed the image from ACR to AKS.

I have created a windows node using AKS windows preview

```
C:\Users\HTECH>kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                STATUS   ROLES   AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                    KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
aks-nodepool1-36563144-vmss000000   Ready    agent   2d3h   v1.14.0   10.240.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS          4.15.0-1042-azure   docker://3.0.4
akssample000000                     Ready    agent   2d2h   v1.14.0   10.240.0.35   <none>        Windows Server Datacenter   10.0.17763.379      docker://18.9.2
```

Docker File:

```
FROM microsoft/iis:latest
SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

COPY . ewims
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'sample' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\sample' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80
```

Manifest YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: samplecloudpoc-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5   
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: samplecloudpoc-v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: samplecloudpoc-v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: samplecloudpoc-v1
        image: samplecloud.azurecr.io/sample:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
        - name: dev
          value: "samplecloudpoc-v1"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: sampleauth
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: samplecloudpoc-v1
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: 13.90.205.141
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: samplecloudpoc-v1
```

While checking the deployement status using below command, I'm getting the following error.

```
D:\Cloud>kubectl describe po samplecloudpoc-v1-5d567d48d9-7gtx8
Name:               samplecloudpoc-v1-5d567d48d9-7gtx8
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               akssample000000/10.240.0.35
Start Time:         Thu, 30 May 2019 13:05:13 +0530
Labels:             app=samplecloudpoc-v1
                    pod-template-hash=5d567d48d9
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.240.0.44
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/samplecloudpoc-v1-5d567d48d9
Containers:
  sample:
    Container ID:  docker://0cf6c92b15738c2786caca5b989aa2773c9375352cb4f1d95472ff63cc7b5112
    Image:         samplecloud.azurecr.io/sample:v1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://samplecloud.azurecr.io/sample@sha256:55ac14dc512abc0f8deebb8b87ee47d51fdfbfd997ce6cee0ab521bd69d42b08
    Port:          80/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      -it
    State:       Waiting
      Reason:    CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:  Terminated
      Reason:    ContainerCannotRun
      Message:   CreateComputeSystem 0cf6c92b15738c2786caca5b989aa2773c9375352cb4f1d95472ff63cc7b5112: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"0cf6c92b15738c2786caca5b989aa2773c9375352cb4f1d95472ff63cc7b5112","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{f5ff1135-4e83-4baa-961d-f4533dcb6985}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0cf6c92b15738c2786caca5b989aa2773c9375352cb4f1d95472ff63cc7b5112","Layers":[{"ID":"b3b88c23-310f-5e95-86bc-117e9f6a6184","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0cc15446c028e2fe68601b10a1921a809dedb2a981162c4ed90344d2fde58f0e"},{"ID":"fb1ae57e-89dc-502c-996b-75804b972adc","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\7217ca2e8bbd2c431c9db44050946ec4f8040c42fdd79f7ceae321e48dc5ca0d"},{"ID":"bb5e3864-b1af-51c8-a8e4-63d88749f082","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\16f07ffe70a600c95bea2e8297c04cbb6af877562c2cc2ac1693267b152d3793"},{"ID":"2fae8c16-582f-5ab1-acfe-0a88980adec3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\a325070d766dd4af490b433d75eac6e1d71297961d89011e5798949eae2e7e4a"},{"ID":"dffd6df2-a500-5985-9c9c-1bc03c9efce3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\1221f773d66647fd1dc7aad44693f28843c8385612edb520231c1cb754eb2f97"},{"ID":"7e349a26-81b9-554e-aa13-a6e4286de93e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\67d6d22eae7f829e590fde792c6b8129aff3d9f9242850fe72e8d167e284a6b7"},{"ID":"8730db1a-385d-5e9a-a4ec-c45525b5fcb3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\2a53ed97b10bd4f67e62e8511e8922496651f3d343dd1889425ba1bedca134fa"},{"ID":"d1e23520-6c0b-5909-8e52-bb6961f80876","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\d3a27083556be1bb7e36997f0eee2b544f6a16eab94797715bc21db99bf42e88"},{"ID":"18d8ab30-09e9-54e3-a991-f48cca651c8d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9b4143f537ff70f6b1e05b2a5e38e3b05dd2a4b2f624822e32bb2b7cd17b7cca"},{"ID":"2acb6fa3-f27c-50cf-9033-eedb06d5bf32","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\f71b6708cc4045bf9633f971dd4d6eddb1c5ffeda52d38e648c740e0e277b2df"},{"ID":"0dc40cf1-482a-5fed-af35-c5d1902b95ae","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\100f3380579a77f2fb2c0f997201e34a0dd2c42e4b0d9a39fb850706aa16e474"}],"ProcessorWeight":5000,"HostName":"samplecloudpoc-v1-5d567d48d9-7gtx8","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\var\\lib\\kubelet\\pods\\75f48f65-82ad-11e9-8e99-a24a72224ed5\\volumes\\kubernetes.io~secret\\default-token-67g2m","ContainerPath":"c:\\var\\run\\secrets\\kubernetes.io\\serviceaccount","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":false,"NetworkSharedContainerName":"d11237887aec604bfbb9b3cd56fca586975e5a92e04dab4d4ba19b1fcc56ed99"})
      Exit Code:    128
      Started:      Thu, 30 May 2019 13:25:00 +0530
      Finished:     Thu, 30 May 2019 13:25:00 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Limits:
      cpu:  100m
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      dev:  samplecloudpoc-v1
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-67g2m (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-67g2m:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-67g2m
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                      Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                      -------
  Normal   Scheduled  21m                    default-scheduler         Successfully assigned default/samplecloudpoc-v1-5d567d48d9-7gtx8 to akssample000000
  Normal   Pulling    21m                    kubelet, akssample000000  Pulling image "samplecloud.azurecr.io/sample:v1"
  Normal   Pulled     4m31s                  kubelet, akssample000000  Successfully pulled image "samplecloud.azurecr.io/sample:v1"
  Normal   Created    3m (x5 over 4m31s)     kubelet, akssample000000  Created container sample
  Normal   Pulled     3m (x4 over 4m28s)     kubelet, akssample000000  Container image "samplecloud.azurecr.io/sample:v1" already present on machine
  Warning  Failed     2m59s (x5 over 4m30s)  kubelet, akssample000000  Error: failed to start container "sample": Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem sample: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"sample","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{f5ff1135-4e83-4baa-961d-f4533dcb6985}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\sample","Layers":[{"ID":"b3b88c23-310f-5e95-86bc-117e9f6a6184","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0cc15446c028e2fe68601b10a1921a809dedb2a981162c4ed90344d2fde58f0e"},{"ID":"fb1ae57e-89dc-502c-996b-75804b972adc","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\7217ca2e8bbd2c431c9db44050946ec4f8040c42fdd79f7ceae321e48dc5ca0d"},{"ID":"bb5e3864-b1af-51c8-a8e4-63d88749f082","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\16f07ffe70a600c95bea2e8297c04cbb6af877562c2cc2ac1693267b152d3793"},{"ID":"2fae8c16-582f-5ab1-acfe-0a88980adec3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\a325070d766dd4af490b433d75eac6e1d71297961d89011e5798949eae2e7e4a"},{"ID":"dffd6df2-a500-5985-9c9c-1bc03c9efce3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\1221f773d66647fd1dc7aad44693f28843c8385612edb520231c1cb754eb2f97"},{"ID":"7e349a26-81b9-554e-aa13-a6e4286de93e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\67d6d22eae7f829e590fde792c6b8129aff3d9f9242850fe72e8d167e284a6b7"},{"ID":"8730db1a-385d-5e9a-a4ec-c45525b5fcb3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\2a53ed97b10bd4f67e62e8511e8922496651f3d343dd1889425ba1bedca134fa"},{"ID":"d1e23520-6c0b-5909-8e52-bb6961f80876","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\d3a27083556be1bb7e36997f0eee2b544f6a16eab94797715bc21db99bf42e88"},{"ID":"18d8ab30-09e9-54e3-a991-f48cca651c8d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9b4143f537ff70f6b1e05b2a5e38e3b05dd2a4b2f624822e32bb2b7cd17b7cca"},{"ID":"2acb6fa3-f27c-50cf-9033-eedb06d5bf32","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\f71b6708cc4045bf9633f971dd4d6eddb1c5ffeda52d38e648c740e0e277b2df"},{"ID":"0dc40cf1-482a-5fed-af35-c5d1902b95ae","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\100f3380579a77f2fb2c0f997201e34a0dd2c42e4b0d9a39fb850706aa16e474"}],"ProcessorWeight":5000,"HostName":"samplecloudpoc-v1-5d567d48d9-7gtx8","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\var\\lib\\kubelet\\pods\\75f48f65-82ad-11e9-8e99-a24a72224ed5\\volumes\\kubernetes.io~secret\\default-token-67g2m","ContainerPath":"c:\\var\\run\\secrets\\kubernetes.io\\serviceaccount","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":false,"NetworkSharedContainerName":"d11237887aec604bfbb9b3cd56fca586975e5a92e04dab4d4ba19b1fcc56ed99"})
  Warning  BackOff  119s (x10 over 3m59s)  kubelet, akssample000000  Back-off restarting failed container
```

I have tried to fix this by pulling the latest version IIS image from docker also throws the same error.

Comment: How do you create the AKS? It seems you do not have the windows node.

Comment: Please check the question again

Comment: Can you check again with the command `kubectl get nodes -o wide`? It could show more details about the nodes.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the details in the question itself

Comment: With my test, maybe it's a mistake. Try to change the apiVersion into apps/v1.

Comment: After changing to apps/v1 I'm getting the below error
D:\Cloud>kubectl get po
NAME                                 READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
ewqimscloudpoc-v1-76b6c6c465-pj9cc   0/1     RunContainerError   0          7s

D:\Cloud>kubectl describe ewqimscloudpoc-v1-76b6c6c465-pj9cc
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "ewqimscloudpoc-v1-76b6c6c465-pj9cc"

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem, the issue was that my node in Kubernetes was running in Windows 2019 and my images was built with Windows 2016.

To check the Windows version for your image:

```
docker inspect <image>:<tag>
```

Then you can get nods with kubectl to view the Windows version of your node:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

To resolve it, I re-build my image from a Windows 2019 machine and then it worked from AKS.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the issue is with the fact AKS doesnt yet support windows nodes, so you dont really have windows nodes. You can create AKS with windows nodes, but its in preview at this point in time.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/master/previews.md#windows

If you have windows nodes, you'd need to make sure that the base image you are using matches the windows host os version

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility

Comment: I'm using the windows preview in AKS

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to change the apiVersion into apps/v1, then the pod will run well. I test the apiVersion as yours and also get the error "Back-off restarting failed container".

Comment: After changing to apps/v1 I'm getting the below error `After changing to apps/v1 I'm getting the below error D:\Cloud>kubectl get po NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE ewqimscloudpoc-v1-76b6c6c465-pj9cc 0/1 RunContainerError 0 7s D:\Cloud>kubectl describe ewqimscloudpoc-v1-76b6c6c465-pj9cc error: the server doesn't have a resource type "ewqimscloudpoc-v1-76b6c6c465-pj9cc"`

Comment: @Hub Change the `apiVersion` with value `apps/v1` and delete the container property `args` with value `["-it"]` int the yaml file.

Comment: After changing as you said also same issue

Comment: @Hub I test your base image in your Dockerfile and it works fine with my pieces of advice. Do you delete and recreate the deployment after change the yaml file?

Comment: Yes I have deleted the deployment and recreated it

Comment: @Hub I confuse that why the node name is akssample000000, not aksewqims000000 in the pod event. In my side, it shows the node name in the event the same as I get through the command `kubectl get nodes`.

Comment: @Hub Can you run the base image that used your Dockerfile on windows node?

Comment: No I have just replaced the project name with the sample for privacy reasons, but i missed that in kubectl get nodes command

Comment: Yes will try and let you know

Comment: Still I'm getting the same Error: failed to start container "sample": Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem sample: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.

Comment: @Hub I think there is some wrong with your cluster. How do you create the AKS cluster?

Comment: I have followed the instruction in this link and created the AKS cluster as they said
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli

Comment: But base image microsoft/iis:latest is working fine while deployed in the same AKS cluster

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, I've created an ASP.NET image from "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8" and it fails to start from AKS with The container operating system does not match the host operating system.